# How to apply if function to a field inside another field?

Tags: if-statement, awk, filter, field

I have a table that I want to filter by awk. This is an example of how I want to do it:

```
Berlin  BG  AD=14;CD=0.05 
Cairo   CE  AD=9;CD=0.01 
Toronto TC  AD=23;CD=0.17
Sydney  SA  AD=2;CD=0.11 
Tokyo   TJ  AD=19;CD=0.22
```

I want to filter the fields based on the AD value and output all fields if in that line AD is equal to or greater than 10.

The result should be like that:

```
Berlin  BG  AD=14;CD=0.05
Toronto TC  AD=23;CD=0.17
Tokyo   TJ  AD=19;CD=0.22
```

I tried this script:

```
awk '{if (awk '{print $3}' temp.txt | awk -F";" '{print $1}' | awk -F"=" '{print $2}' >= 10) print $0}' temp.txt
```

But it gave me such a syntax error about an unexpected newline or end of the string

Comment: What's that first line? `awk '{if (awk...` Doesn't make sense. You can't call awk from within awk.

Comment: Please don't remove your samples and tried code in your question else it will make your question difficult to understand.

Comment: could you explain how the input is formatted?  at the moment it looks like one long line with each city group delimited by a pipe (`|`) ... is this correct?

Comment: Regarding `awk '{if (awk ...` - awk is not shell. You can't directly call other commands (including `awk`) from an awk script.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With your shown samples and in GNU `awk` you could try following `awk` code. Using `match` function of `awk` where mentioning regex `[[:space:]]+(AD=)([0-9]+)` which creates 2 capturing group and stores matched values into array named arr. Then checking condition if 2nd value is greater than 10 then print that line.

```bash
awk '
match($0,/[[:space:]]+(AD=)([0-9]+)/,arr) && arr[2]>10
'  Input_file
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `awk` you can use a pattern to match a space, then `AD=` and 1 or more digits. The number value starts after the first 4 characters of the match and you can compare that with greater than 10:

```
awk '
match($0,/[[:space:]]AD=[0-9]+/) {
  if (substr($0, RSTART +4, RLENGTH-4)+0 > 10) print
}
' file
```

Input

```
Berlin BG AD=14;CD=0.05
Cairo CE AD=9;CD=0.01
Toronto TC AD=23;CD=0.17
Sydney SA AD=2;CD=0.11
Tokyo TJ AD=19;CD=0.22
```

Output

```
Berlin BG AD=14;CD=0.05
Toronto TC AD=23;CD=0.17
Tokyo TJ AD=19;CD=0.22
```

---

If the input has pipes `|` you could make it the field separator surrounded with optional whitespace chars, and print  `|`  as the field separator for the output:

```
awk '
BEGIN{ FS="[[:space:]]*[|][[:space:]]*" }
{
  s=""
  for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
    if (match($i,/[[:space:]]AD=[0-9]+/) && substr($i, RSTART+4, RLENGTH-4)+0 > 10) {
      s=s (s == "" ? $i : " | " $i)
    }
  }
}
END { print s }
' file
```

Input

```
| Berlin BG AD=14;CD=0.05 | Cairo CE AD=9;CD=0.01 | Toronto TC AD=23;CD=0.17 | Sydney SA AD=2;CD=0.11 | Tokyo TJ AD=19;CD=0.22
```

Output

```
Berlin BG AD=14;CD=0.05 | Toronto TC AD=23;CD=0.17 | Tokyo TJ AD=19;CD=0.22
```

Answer (score 2):

Using any awk:

```
$ awk -F'[;=]' '$2 >= 10' file
Berlin  BG  AD=14;CD=0.05
Toronto TC  AD=23;CD=0.17
Tokyo   TJ  AD=19;CD=0.22
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm confused about the format of the input:

- OP mentions a 'table' but ...
- provided sample shows one long line of city groups separated by spaces and pipes but ...
- OP's code attempt has no reference to pipes (so, are there no pipes in the data file?)

For this answer I'm going to assume the following format:

```
$ cat temp.txt
Berlin BG AD=14;CD=0.05
Cairo CE AD=9;CD=0.01
Toronto TC AD=23;CD=0.17
Sydney SA AD=2;CD=0.11
Tokyo TJ AD=19;CD=0.22
```

Setting aside the syntax issues with OP's current code, there's no need for 3x separate `awk` scripts (ie, we should be able to generate the desired result with a single `awk` script).

One `awk` idea:

```
##########
# assuming the "AD=" entry is always the first item in the 3rd field (as displayed in the sample input):

awk '
{ n=split($3,a,"[;=]")                      # split 3rd field on dual delimiters ";" and "="; store results in array a[]
  if (a[1] == "AD" && a[2] >= 10)           # if 1st array entry == "AD" and 2nd array entry >= 10 then ...
     print                                  # print current line
}
' temp.txt

##########
# assuming the "AD=" entry could occur anywhere in the 3rd field:

awk '
{ n=split($3,a,"[;=]")                      # split 3rd field on dual delimiters ";" and "="; store results in array a[]
  for (i=1;i<n;i+=2)                        # loop through odd-numbered indices
      if (a[i] == "AD" && a[i+1] >= 10)     # if current array entry =="AD" and next array entry >= 10 then ...
         print                              # print current line
}
' temp.txt
```

These both generate:

```
Berlin BG AD=14;CD=0.05
Toronto TC AD=23;CD=0.17
Tokyo TJ AD=19;CD=0.22
```

---

Modifying to allow dynamic assignment of the 'attribute/threshold' pair:

```
awk -v attrib="AD" -v thresh="10" '
{ n=split($3,a,"[;=]")
  for (i=1;i<n;i+=2)
      if (a[i] == attrib && a[i+1] >= thresh)
         print
}
' temp.txt
```

For `-v attrib="AD" -v thresh="10"` this generates:

```
Berlin BG AD=14;CD=0.05
Toronto TC AD=23;CD=0.17
Tokyo TJ AD=19;CD=0.22
```

For `-v attrib="CD" -v thresh=".13"` this generates:

```
Toronto TC AD=23;CD=0.17
Tokyo TJ AD=19;CD=0.22
```

Answer (score 1):

don't make it more complicated than what's needed :

> ```
> mawk -F= '10 < +$2'
> ```

```
Berlin  BG  AD=14;CD=0.05 
Toronto TC  AD=23;CD=0.17
Tokyo   TJ  AD=19;CD=0.22
```